# How to find eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Good afternoon,

I have some problem finding the eigenvectors for matrix
$  \begin{pmatrix} 
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 1  
   \end{pmatrix} $

I found eigen values $\mu=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ and $\lambda=\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.
But when I try to find eigenvectors I am blocked with the system :
\begin{align*}
  &\begin{cases}
  y = \mu x\\
  x + y = \mu y
  \end{cases} \\
  \iff 
  &\begin{cases}
  y = \mu x\\
  x +(1-\mu) \mu x = 0
  \end{cases}\\
  \iff 
  &\begin{cases}
  y = \mu x\\
  x(-\mu^2 + \mu +1)=0
  \end{cases}   
 \end{align*}

But $(-\mu^2 + \mu +1)=0$ so I don't know how to continue. I wonder if x could be any value (1 for example) then I deduce y, but it doesn't work. Did I make a mistake?
Thanks you for your help .

Comment: You say it doesn't work. Could you be note detailed as to how you can tell it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made no mistake, and the part that you said "It doesn't work" has to do with finding $x$. You would have expected that an $x$ could be solved for from the second equation: $x\cdot 0 = 0$. This equation has infinitely many solutions $x$. And the eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue is of the form $(c,\mu c), c\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-\mu^2+\mu+1=0$, the second equation is just $0=0$. All that remains is the equation $y=\mu x$. So, an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\mu$ is $(1,\mu)$. (I took $x=1$, as you suggested. Any number different from $0$ will do.)

You can check that it works by computing$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.(1,\mu)-\mu(1,\mu).$$It is equal to $(0,1+\mu-\mu^2)=(0,0)$. So, the method works.

Comment: @Arthur I have added more details. But it seemed to me that the OP got confused by the fact that the second equation became $0=0$.

Comment: Then addressing the inherent homogeneity of eigenvector equations in general could also be a good idea.

Comment: Actually I  was confused with 0x=0 and that $1+\mu=\mu^2$ but everything was finally right.Thanks you very much

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.